# iOS, using sizing class font size with code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autolayout

I thought I'd try and reuse the font settings and size class variations in my own view. I have my drawing code within drawRect within a UILabel class. However the size of the font isn't that I've set with my sizing classes.

OK, I know I'm not using the label as intended, but shouldn't this work ?

```
H
=
IB_DESIGNABLE
@interface TitleBannerView : UILabel

M
=
@implementation TitleBannerView

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    NSLog(@"self.font.pointSize=%f", self.font.pointSize);

    UIFont* textFont = [UIFont fontWithName:APP_FONT size:self.font.pointSize];

    //reuse the font in my drawing code here

    //Don't add the label!
    //[super drawRect: rect];
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the system font in IB with all your sizing classed and use this method.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UILabelEx : UILabel


@end

#import "UILabelEx.h"
#import "Constants.h"

@implementation UILabelEx

- (void) traitCollectionDidChange: (UITraitCollection *) previousTraitCollection {
    [super traitCollectionDidChange: previousTraitCollection];

    self.font = [UIFont fontWithName:APP_FONT size:self.font.pointSize];   
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try preferredFontDescriptorWithTextStyle which respect the user's selected content size category as described [here](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/supporting-dynamic-type.html).

```
UIFontDescriptor *userFont = [UIFontDescriptor preferredFontDescriptorWithTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody];
float userFontSize = [userFont pointSize];
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:APP_FONT size:userFontSize];
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't give the size from the sizing class as shown.

Comment: Did you set FontDescriptor in storyboard? If so I have no idea :s

Comment: FontDescriptor can't see that?

Comment: Select label, attributes inspector, click on T to the right at Font. Then in Font you select text style (might ruin your custom font).

Comment: Oh right, I have a custom font and I'm not using dynamics

Comment: Thanks so much, anyways